# Only keep latest 50 related Entities and autoprune older ones with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is there a (built-in) way with Entity Framework (6) that would allow me to only keep the latest N related elements of a particular, related entity?

E.g. if I have an entity named 'Post' that has 0..* related 'Visitors', I'd like to only keep 50 of the latter and automatically get rid of (delete the visitors from the underlying database) older ones once that threshold is reached. Is that doable, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no auto-prune feature in EF at all. You would have to build a query that gets executed each time to determine if you've gone over the 50 visitor limit.

You'll have to build a query that targets 'visit' 51+ and then enumerate through them to call a delete on the entries. Unfortunately Entity Framework has no batch functionality for updates or deletes, so you'd have to perform *individual* deletes on those items. Assuming you build up a slow number of visitors over time, this shouldn't be an issue, but I would highly suggest not doing it this way - if you have a lot of visitors, your performance is going to be in the toilet.

I would suggest looking at one of the Entity Framework extension projects that use the underlying connection via ADO to produce the necessary delete and update statements that can properly target those older visits in one swoop. Each project has it's own guide to building those queries, but they generate a single SQL call underneath to complete the work quickly and efficiently.